# mime.lookUp is not a function in my React typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was running my React project today and after running it I received the error below. I am confused on how to fix this as I have never used `mime.lookup` in my project. Could someone please help me?

```
/Users/lebanissa/Desktop/waitlist-backend/waitlist-frontend/node_modules/send/index.js:838
  var type = mime.lookup(path)
                  ^
```

```
 TypeError: mime.lookup is not a function
    at SendStream.type (/Users/lebanissa/Desktop/waitlist-backend/waitlist-frontend/node_modules/send/index.js:838:19)
    at SendStream.send (/Users/lebanissa/Desktop/waitlist-backend/waitlist-frontend/node_modules/send/index.js:627:8)
    at onstat (/Users/lebanissa/Desktop/waitlist-backend/waitlist-frontend/node_modules/send/index.js:729:10)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:184:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: The error is coming from the [send](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send) package rather than from your project itself.  You can try updating this package to the latest version.  More likely you are using a function from the `send` package with invalid arguments that are causing it to fail down the chain.  Looks like the error is in an `oncomplete` callback.